# chrome.tabs.create not working on Chrome 69

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome.tabs.create function being called within my chrome extension. In the past, whenever I call this function from within the extension the user's view would change to the the latest Tab that the extension called. Now with Chrome 69, the new tab get's created in the background and within my extension it looks like there is no action taken by the extension

```
  $('#click-link').click(function(){
    chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://signup.com/signup'});
  });
```

Comment: Works correctly for me. Sounds like you have another extension that modifies the way tabs are opened by default. There are several such extensions around.

Comment: That's weird, could you try this extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/akamai-developer-toolkit/oeekflkhfpllpepjdkpodopelgaebeed?hl=en-US) and click on the  "submit feedback" button? I click on it and my view does not change to the latest tab I create instead it still stays within the extension itself.

Comment: It switches to the tab alright. Try creating a new browser profile with just that extension.

Comment: hmm, tried with a different browser profile, same behavior. Maybe something's up with my laptop. Thanks you for confirming that it's working as expected. Will ask a few more folks to test it out and revisit this thread

Comment: Could be OS-specific. I've tested in Win7.